# iterm2 different directory for sourcing zshrc

Tags: terminal, shell, zsh, iterm2

I started playing around with shell scripting and set up zsh via iTerm2 on my MacBook. I set a zsh directory in `.config` so to organise my `.zshrc` and `.zshenv` config files, but when I launch iTerm2 it does not automatically source the file from said directory. Instead, they must stay in my `$HOME` dir.

How do I change this setting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about iTerm2 (macOS's built-in Terminal app works fine for me), but to make Zsh read your config files from a different dir than `$HOME`, you need to set the [`$ZDOTDIR` parameter](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-ZDOTDIR).

Comment: In the end, I came to this same conclusion! I had a look at the `/private/etc/` folder and found there was no `zshenv` item, so I created one and added the following:

```
export ZDOTDIR="$HOME/.config/zsh"

```

And now it works! I had to create said file because zsh documentation says it is the first to be read.